# Communication between ignition and ROS2 (via gazebo_ros_pkgs/ros_gz_bridge etc)

Tags: ros2, ros-foxy, ignition-citadel, gazebo-ros2-control

I have a dilemma here:

1. I want to test my controller nodes (written in ROS2) on bluerov2 ignition model (https://github.com/clydemcqueen/bluerov2_ignition).
2. I installed Ignition Citadel (tried Garden and other but this one works with ROS2 foxy).
3. I installed the ROS2 foxy.
4. In order to communicate between ROS2 and ignition I installed ros_gz_bridge (https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/foxy). Now I can send commands using mavproxy server and simple messages, but i wan tot establish ros communication
   The problem is that when I run the gz bluerov2 model, I run the bridge, and I check the ros2 topic list I can see the gz topics but when I echo them, nothing happens, I don't see any values coming.
5. I tried to work with "gazebo_ros_pkgs" (https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/foxy) I git clone it and colcon build it I receive this error:

> Starting >>> gazebo_plugins
> --- stderr: gazebo_plugins                          CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package):   By not providing
> "Findgazebo_dev.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project   has asked
> CMake to find a package configuration file provided by   "gazebo_dev",
> but CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo_dev"
> with   any of the following names:
>
> ```
> gazebo_devConfig.cmake
> gazebo_dev-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "gazebo_dev" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
> set   "gazebo_dev_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
> files.  If   "gazebo_dev" provides a separate development package or
> SDK, be sure it has   been installed.
>
> --- Failed   <<< gazebo_plugins [1.06s, exited with code 1]
>
> Summary: 0 packages finished [3.90s]   1 package failed:
> gazebo_plugins   1 package had stderr output: gazebo_plugins

After that i follow this link (https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros2_installing&cat=connect_ros) and try to install the gazebo_ros_pkgs and I receive the error:

> Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some
> packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested
> an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution
> that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved
> out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the
> situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> ros-foxy-gazebo-ros-pkgs :
>
> Depends: ros-foxy-gazebo-dev but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: ros-foxy-gazebo-plugins but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: ros-foxy-gazebo-ros but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
> broken packages.

How to establish the ROS communication with the ignition model? It seems like I am stuck between the two facts:

- that the model works with ignition only and doesn't support the gazebo_ros_pkgs
- if I want to use the ignition bridge I don't see any data published by the model, however it is running and I can communicate with it through mavproxy by sending commands manually.

I will be very grateful for your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Focusing on Gazebo Citadel that works with ros_gz bridge: by any chance did you press the play button or run the simulation with the -r argument to start the simulation? Were you able to echo de gz topics (outside of ROS)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with your original problem, but gazebo_ros_pkgs is not for use with ignition:
Don't mix gazebo (former ignition, with ROS packages named ign* or gz*) with gazebo classic (former "gazebo", with ROS packages named gazebo*).

Do you really have to stay on ROS 2 Foxy? It is in end-of-life state, and it might be that something is not working any more there.

Comment: Well, unfortunately everything comes from the fact that the model has to work on Gazebo Citadel and one of the best options to work with it is ROS2 Foxy. (as far as I know).